# why showImageNumberLabel option does not affect lightbox default setting?

Tags: lightbox2

I added 3 images in one page that one link triggers them, completely standard.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
<a href="img/nibe-cert.jpg" data-lightbox="nibe-cert" data-title="ISO 9001-14001 SERTİFİKASI">
<img alt="Nibe Cert" class="border--round box-shadow-wide" src="img/nibe-cert.jpg">
<a href="img/nibe-cert-2.jpg" data-lightbox="nibe-cert" data-title="ÇEVRE POLİTİKASI"></a>
<a href="img/nibe-cert-3.jpg" data-lightbox="nibe-cert" data-title="KALİTE POLİTİKASI"></a>
</a>
</div>
```

And I added:

```
 <script>
    lightbox.option({
        "showImageNumberLabel": false
    });
</script>
```

But I still can see the text: image 1 from 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have to set an extra option, although the documentation does not mention directly that this option is related to `showImageNumberLabel`.

Your code needs `"albumLabel": false`, so it becomes:

```
<script>
    lightbox.option({
        "albumLabel": false,
        "showImageNumberLabel": false
    });
</script>
```